# org.h2.mvstore.MVStoreException: The file is locked: when running "mvn clean package" but works fine when running "mvn clean package -DskipTests"

Tags: java, maven, h2, liquibase

I have a Liquibase and an H2 in my Spring Boot project.

I use persistent file (h2:file) for H2 instead of in-memory (h2:mem) approach.

When I run project with just play button (IntelliJ IDEA, Run Project) app runs fine; however, when I build it with `mvn clean package` it outputs:

```java
 Caused by: org.h2.mvstore.MVStoreException: The file is locked: C:/path/to/database/data.mv.db [2.1.214/7]
        at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newMVStoreException(DataUtils.java:1004)
        at org.h2.mvstore.FileStore.open(FileStore.java:178)
        at org.h2.mvstore.FileStore.open(FileStore.java:128)
        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.<init>(MVStore.java:452)
        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$Builder.open(MVStore.java:4082)
        at org.h2.mvstore.db.Store.<init>(Store.java:136)
        ... 115 more
```

and it does so even if I empty `C:/path/to/database` folder and run app again (so, at the first startup).

I speculated a bit and tried to run it without test phase, like:

```java
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

and it then worked.

This is my `application.properties` if it matters:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./database/data

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.liquibase.change-log=db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

What's the point? any tips?

### Update

If I just remove Liquibase dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

then H2 works fine and persists data in file.